# SharePoint VS development - tuning changes without redeployment

Tags: development, debugging

I have VS project with .wsp containing custom forms for list. I need to tune some details on the form - sometimes in aspx file, sometimes in code behind (.cs).

What are the options to tune it without re-deploying wsp after every change (it takes long time to retract, recycle apppool, deploy,..)?

I can edit .aspx directly in 15\TEMPLATES\FEATURES subfolder but still the compiled code is cached - can I (temporarily) disable caching for the development? How about codebehind?

I would appreciate any tips on efficient development (how to quicky tune/test smaller changes).

(SharePoint 2013, Visual Studio 2013, Windows Server 2012R2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a user control, you can just replace the .acsx file in the Layouts folder. But if it is a C# file, you need to build the project without changing the assembly version and copy that into the GAC (assembly folder).

There are some third party VS tools such like [CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/).

Comment: CKSDev is pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

For Aspx as you say, you can directly edit the aspx page from 15 hive folder.
For code behind changes you have to redeploy the dll. So you can replace the changed code dll in GAC using gacutil command. After replacement app pool recycle/iisreset is required.